# What is the easiest way to change a object's properties which are in b without override the object?

Tags: javascript

Let's see an example

```js
const a = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3
}
const b = {
  1: "a",
  2: "b",
  3: "c",
  4: "d",
  5: "e"
}
//expected
{
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: "d",
  5: "e"
}
```

How to earn the above result? I want to change the properties at b from a, but letting properties exist where it's not existing at a.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Object.assign()`. And pass `a` as an argument after `b`, so that a overrides  the properties that are present in it.

```js
const a = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3
}
const b = {
  1: "a",
  2: "b",
  3: "c",
  4: "d",
  5: "e"
}

let result = Object.assign({},b,a);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Object.assign()`:

```js
const a = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3
}
const b = {
  1: "a",
  2: "b",
  3: "c",
  4: "d",
  5: "e"
}
var res = Object.assign({},b,a);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use new ES6 syntax for that:

```
const a = { 
  1: 1,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
};

const b = {
  1: 'a',
  2: 'b',
  3: 'c',
  4: 'd',
  5: 'e',
};

const result = { ...b, ...a };
```